# Uncaught OAuthException

Tags: php, facebook

Guys please help me out with this...the error which my program gives is "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating application"...
My program code is :

```
require ("src/facebook.php");

$appapikey = 'xxx';
$appsecret = 'xxx';

$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

$friends = $facebook->api('friends.get');



echo "<p>Hello <fb:name uid=\"$user_id\" useyou=\"false\" linked=\"false\" firstnameonly=\"true\"></fb:name>, you have ".count($friends)." friends";

foreach($friends as $friend){
     $infos.=$friend.",";
}

$infos = substr($infos,0,strlen($infos)-1);

$gender=$facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($infos,'sex');

$gender_array = array(); 

foreach($gender as $gendervalue){
     $gender_array[$gendervalue[sex]]++;
}

$male = round($gender_array[male]*100/($gender_array[male]+$gender_array[female]),2);
$female = 100-$male;

echo "<ul><li>Males: $male%</li><li>Females: $female%</li></ul>";
```

Comment: Well first I'd hope you plan on resetting your app's secret very soon, but you seem to be using some very old SDK samples. Are you sure that you do indeed have the app info there correctly, and that the app exists and is properly set up?

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating the Facebook instance correctly. You should use a single parameter (an array) instead of 2 separate parameters. See [Facebook PHP SDK example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) on GIT.

```php
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $appapikey,
    'secret' => $appsecret,
));
```

Comment: bt along with the array... i even added a try - catch block ... as suggested by another person... its givin me this error :

Comment: Error:FacebookApiException Object ( [result:protected] => Array ( [error] => Array ( [type] => OAuthException [message] => Invalid OAuth access token signature. ) ) [message:protected] => Invalid OAuth access token signature. [string:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => E:\HostingSpaces\bombil\bombil.com\wwwroot\genderper\src\facebook.php [line:protected] => 523 [trace:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [function] => _graph [class] => Facebook [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => friends.get ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] =>

Comment: E:\HostingSpaces\bombil\bombil.com\wwwroot\genderper\src\facebook.php [line] => 472 [function] => call_user_func_array [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Facebook Object ( [appId:protected] => [apiSecret:protected] => [session:protected] => [signedRequest:protected] => [sessionLoaded:protected] => 1 [cookieSupport:protected] => [baseDomain:protected] => [fileUploadSupport:protected] => ) [1] => _graph ) [1] => Array ( [0] => friends.get ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [file] =>

Comment: E:\HostingSpaces\bombil\bombil.com\wwwroot\genderper\gender.php [line] => 12 [function] => api [class] => Facebook [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => friends.get ) ) ) )

Comment: Do you have the last version of the [SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tree/master/src)?

Comment: i have sdk 3.0.1 ... and thats the latest i suppose ... please tell me what to do now :(

Comment: I edited my code sample to include the array keys (I forgot them in the first place). Try it now and see if it works for you.

Comment: how do i include array keys ??... im extremely sorry to ask u silly questions ... bt i am a newbie to this ... thanks for your support :)

Comment: I meant I added `'appId'` and `'secret'` keys to the array in my code sample. I didn't use these keys initially. So if you just copy/pasted my first code sample, then you should update your code.

Comment: sorry buddy ...it dint help :(

Comment: output:
Error:FacebookApiException Object ( [result:protected] => Array ( [error] => Array ( [type] => OAuthException [message] => Invalid OAuth access token signature. ) ) [message:protected] => Invalid OAuth access token signature. [string:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => E:\HostingSpaces\bombil\bombil.com\wwwroot\genderper\src\facebook.php [line:protected] => 523 [trace:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [function] => _graph [class] => Facebook [type] => -> [args] => Array

Comment: ( [0] => friends.get ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] => E:\HostingSpaces\bombil\bombil.com\wwwroot\genderper\src\facebook.php [line] => 472 [function] => call_user_func_array [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Facebook Object ( [appId:protected] => [apiSecret:protected] => [session:protected] => [signedRequest:protected] => [sessionLoaded:protected] => 1 [cookieSupport:protected] =

Comment: > [baseDomain:protected] => [fileUploadSupport:protected] => ) [1] => _graph ) [1] => Array ( [0] => friends.get ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [file] => E:\HostingSpaces\bombil\bombil.com\wwwroot\genderper\gender.php [line] => 16 [function] => api [class] => Facebook [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => friends.get ) ) ) )

Comment: I would suggest you to try the [example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) from the SDK. Your posted code is outdated and won't work, even if you solve the OAuth issue. `$facebook->api_client` object doesn't even exist in the latest version of the SDK. Besides, you should use the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and not the old `friends.get` method.